# Extract information from a file name using a bash regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, filenames

I need a regular expression to match and extract groups for a file name that will have the following format:

```
<artifactName>-<version>-<classifier>.<extension>
```

Where:

1. `<artifactName>` can have dashes in it
2. `<version>` must be of the format `X`, `X.Y`, `X.X.Y`, or `X.X.X.Y`, where X is any number of digits and Y is an alphanumeric string that can contain underscores
3. `<classifier>` must be one of the following formats:
   a. `<datestring>b<buildNumber>_<branch>`
   b. `<branch>`
   where `<datestring>` is a 14 digit number, `<buildNumber>` is any number of digits, and `<branch>` is any alphanumeric string that can contain dashes or periods
4. `<extension>` can be any alphanumeric string that can contain underscores

So far I have this regular expression, which works in online regex testers, but it fails when tested in a bash script:

```
^(.+)-((?:[[:digit:]]+\.){0,3}(?:[[:digit:]]+))-((?:([0-9]{14})b([[:digit:]]+)_([^\.]*))|(?:[^\.]*))\.(.+)$
```

The script I am using looks like this:

```
FILE_NAME='some-artifact-1.2.3.4-20180911123456b123_branch.ex.ten.sion'
REGEX='^(.+)-((?:[[:digit:]]+\.){0,3}(?:[[:digit:]]+))-((?:([0-9]{14})b([[:digit:]]+)_([^\.]*))|(?:[^\.]*))\.(.+)$'

if [[ "${FILE_NAME}" =~ ${REGEX} ]]
then
    echo "Artifact     = ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    echo "Version      = ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    echo "Classifier   = ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    echo "Build Date   = ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    echo "Build Number = ${BASH_REMATCH[5]}"
    echo "Branch       = ${BASH_REMATCH[6]}"
    echo "Extension    = ${BASH_REMATCH[7]}"
fi
```

I am assuming the interpreter that bash uses requires a little different syntax, but I cannot figure out how to convert the regular expression that works in the online testers into one that works in bash.

Comment: `bash` uses POSIX regular expressions, not Perl-compatible regexes, so no `(?:...)` non-capture groups.

Comment: (Namely, POSIX extended regular expressions; consult `man re_format` for details.)

Comment: You might try using `pcregrep`

Comment: @chepner Ah that was it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion): It's a bit verbose, but reliable.

```
FILE_NAME='some-artifact-1.2.3.4-20180911123456b123_branch.ex.ten.sion'

art_ver=${FILE_NAME%-*}
artifact=${art_ver%-*}
version=${art_ver##*-}

class_ext=${FILE_NAME##*-}
classification=${class_ext%%.*}
extension=${class_ext#*.}

printf "%s\n" "$artifact" "$version" "$classification" "$extension"
```

```
some-artifact
1.2.3.4
20180911123456b123_branch
ex.ten.sion
```

---

I just read your requirements more carefully: if the branch can contain dots and the extension can contain dots, it is impossible to determine where the branch stops and the extension begins.